# Convert `IntoIterator<Item = T>` into `IntoIterator<Item = &T>`?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a value of type `impl IntoIterator<Item = T>` and a function that accepts `impl IntoIterator<Item = &T>`. In general, is there any way to convert between the two or am I out of luck (Edit: without cloning or collecting first)?

Comment: You could do `input.in to_iterator().map(|x| &x)`. Note however, that this will consume the original iterator. If you would like to use it multiple times, you should collect it first (for example to a `Vec`), and then you can pass `&vec` to the other function multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to say without cloning or collecting first.

Comment: No. You would need to keep the `T`s around somewhere so that all the `&T`s are valid. In general, you can’t do this without collecting the `T`s.